# Facebook SDK for Unity - Multiple Highscores

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

just a quick question :)

Does Facebook allow you to save multiple highscores?

For example, Candy crush has a high score for every level (of which there are hundreds), however searching on Google has told me that Facebook only has the ability to save one main highscore list per game.

Does that mean I have to save highscores on my own database? Or does Facebook have the ability to handle more than one highscore list now?

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook's Score API can only hold 1 score per game. Candy Crush is using a custom Open Graph story to mimic the Score API for each level, so they are storing each high score in their backend.